# Measuring colors from images through Histograms

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, matplotlib

I'm trying to make a kind of colorimeter of white to yellow scales.

I'll try to better explain, but since I'm new at Python and Image Processing, please correct me If I say something wrong.

I'm using HSV colorspace as I read that it can better represent the color features in three components (hue, saturation and value). Supposing I have an image with some shades of white, the program should be able to calculate a value based on the pixel's hue, saturation and value of the image, as If I provide an image with slightly white to yellow shades, it should give similar value.

Here is an example of [image of sugar crystals](http://rkintl.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/sugar-crystals-photograph.jpg). The sugar has shades of both white and yellow, when ignoring the purple background.

My first attempt was calculating a histogram of an almost totally white image and using it as reference, then calculate another image's histogram and compare them to check if they're similar. As more yellow it is, less similar it should be, remembering that a single image can have both white and yellow pixels, or even a range of different yellow shades in hue histogram):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

image = cv2.imread("C:\...\im1.png")
image2 = cv2.imread("C:\...\im2.png")

hsv_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
hsv_image2 = cv2.cvtColor(image2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

hue_hist = cv2.calcHist([hsv_image], [0], None, [180], [0, 180])
sat_hist = cv2.calcHist([hsv_image], [1], None, [256], [0, 256])
val_hist = cv2.calcHist([hsv_image], [2], None, [256], [0, 256])

hue_hist2 = cv2.calcHist([hsv_image2], [0], None, [180], [0, 180])
sat_hist2 = cv2.calcHist([hsv_image2], [1], None, [256], [0, 256])
val_hist2 = cv2.calcHist([hsv_image2], [2], None, [256], [0, 256])

dh = cv2.compareHist(hue_hist, hue_hist2, cv2.cv.CV_COMP_CORREL)
ds = cv2.compareHist(sat_hist, sat_hist2, cv2.cv.CV_COMP_CORREL)
dv = cv2.compareHist(val_hist, val_hist2, cv2.cv.CV_COMP_CORREL)
```

After that, I would have those three separated values indicating both histogram's similarity in hue, saturation and value,
then I could try some mathematical modelling in order to obtain some y score value for each combination of dh, ds, dv.

Problem with that is, If you compare the hue histogram of a yellow pixels image, the correlation comparison will indicate that they're totally different, even they could be interpreted as similar because of a slightly change in white to yellow shades. I need something that doesn't rely only on frequency of the pixels on the histogram, but also the proximity of the hue values.

Another solution I thought, was to calculate the weighted mean of the histogram, so maybe I could have a closer value 
for similar distributions even If comparing an image with a peak of pixels with 30 hue and another image with a peak 
of pixels with 25 hue (they would not be TOTALLY away from each other). I didn't try this one yet.

Do you know if there's a better way to achieve that, or at least If I'm on the right way to do such application?

Comment: How do you want to handle a completely black image?

Comment: Actually, for my specific purpose I won't have to process black images, but If I do, I would expect to detect it as a completly out of specification color, since I'm interested in white to yellow colors.

Comment: Images of sugar crystals can ilustrate the kind of processing I'm trying to do, since you will  have different levels of colors from white to yellow.

Answer (score 2):

To get the "yellowness" of an image, first take the Hue. Then divide it up into sectors, cut at 180-300-60 (C-M-Y). Anything between 60 and 180 will be a linear combination of yellow and cyan; anything between 60 and 300 will be a linear combination of yellow and magenta. Anything between 160 and 300 will have a yellow value of 0. Convert the linear combination to 0-100% yellow. Call this value `y`.

To get the white "whiteness" use the saturation. S=0 is 100% white, S=30 is 70% white. Call this value `w`.

Then you could do something like

```
yellowness = y / (y + w)
whiteness = w / (y + w)
```

Comment: It seems to be a good idea for linearization, although I'm not sure If it would work simple as that since I could have many different hues for each pixel on the same image. That's why I'm trying to use histograms, evaluating the number of pixels on each hue value, then doing the same for saturation and brightness would provide more accuracy If I apply the right method to compare the histograms. I need something that doesn't rely only on frequency of the pixels, but also the proximity of the hue values.

Comment: This transformation isn't going to stop you from doing histograms. It will just change what your histograms are of. Or did you want a method that doesn't use histograms? And can you elaborate on what you mean by "proximity"?

Comment: No, no, I would like to stick to histograms as I believe they can provide accurate information about how the color components are distributed on an image. When I say proximity, I mean that I need a comparison method that consider the shape of the distribution, then a histogram with 3000 pixels on 29 hue wouldn't be totally away from 3000 pixels on 30 hue. Do you think this would work?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use the HSV space as the Hue of white is undetermined (because of noise, you can get any value).

I would first observe the spread of the pixels in RGB space. (But you didn't provide any sample image.)

Comment: Sounds interesting, I could try some results within RGB colorspace. For HSV, I considered using a filter mask to make sure the hue value was within the limit.

There's an sample [image](http://rkintl.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/sugar-crystals-photograph.jpg).

Desconsidering the purple background, you see that sugar crystals can have shades of white and some yellow too.

Comment: The differences are quite subtle, you will need to work in well controlled conditions, with industrial grade lighting to get reproducible results. Of course a colored background is out of question as it will pollute the whole heap: on this image, you'll find blue sugar.

Comment: "to make sure the hue value was within the limit": this is of no use when the hue is undeterminate.

Comment: @pfnuesel: I disagree. The question is "Do you know if there's a better way to achieve that, or at least If I'm on the right way to do such application?" and I do answer that.